# EF: Databinding checkbox to nullable int value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, checkbox, data-binding

I am wondering if there is a way of handling nullable values of type `int` when binding to a `CheckBox` in Winforms.

Take the following example class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Nullable<int> NULLABLE_INT_VALUE { get; set; }
    public int NON_NULLABLE_VALUE { get; set; }
}
```

I have a component which inherits from the standard checkbox and allows you to pass an object (i.e. the class instance) and a property name and will set a DataBinding against the checkbox:

```
public void FSetDataBinding(object BindingObject, string FieldName)
{
    Binding ControlBinding = new Binding("Checked", BindingObject, FieldName) { NullValue = false };
    ControlBinding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    ControlBinding.Format += (s, e) => { e.Value = e.Value.ToString() == "1"; };
    ControlBinding.Parse += FormDBCheckBox_Parse;
    DataBindings.Add(ControlBinding);
}

private void FormDBCheckBox_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if((bool)(e.Value))
    {
        e.Value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        e.Value = "0";
    }
}
```

If I create two checkbox controls (`chkNullableValue` and `chkNonNullableValue` respectively), I can bind them to a TestClass (we're assuming here that TestClass is an EF version of the database table:

```
TestClass IAmATest = new TestClass() { NULLABLE_INT_VALUE = 1, NON_NULLABLE_VALUE = 0 }
chkNullableValue.FSetDataBinding(IAmATest, "NULLABLE_INT_VALUE");
chkNonNullableValue.FSetDataBinding(IAmATest, "NON_NULLABLE_VALUE");
```

Both properties are from the same object and are bound in exactly the same way; however, when I try and check the box which is bound to the nullable value, for some reason the `(set;)` accessor is never hit against the property. What happens is that, on the form, the box appears to be checked; however, since the underlying property against the box has not been updated, the next time it formats the control for display, `e.Value` is still `"0"` and the box will 'un-check' itself. This also means that calling `SaveChanges()` doesn't update the value, as it has technically never been updated.

**It's also important to note here:** Yes, it's true that `NullValue = false` against the `Binding` that is created; however, in this specific case, the nullable value already has a value of `"0"` and so will never actually be `null` (but it *could* be in other cases).

The opposite is true for the non-nullable property and this behaves exactly as I would expect; when you check the box on the form, the value of `NON_NULLABLE_VALUE` is updated and set to `"1"` as part of `FormDBCheckBox_Parse`, so the next time the control formats itself, `ControlBinding.Format` returns `"true"` and the checked property is set accordingly.

As I'm of the opinion that if something is a flag (and therefore either 'off' or 'on' at all times) then null values shouldn't be allowed against the field in the database and so in the end I just made the value non-nullable; however, I want to understand exactly why I had so much trouble using the nullable type in case I need to use it in future for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the correct binding configuration which works for both `int` and `int?`:

```
public void FSetDataBinding(object BindingObject, string FieldName)
{
    Binding ControlBinding = new Binding("Checked", BindingObject, FieldName, true) { DataSourceNullValue = false };
    ControlBinding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
    DataBindings.Add(ControlBinding);
}
```

Some things to note:

- Always set [`Binding.FormattingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `true` (by either using the constructor overload as above or the property setter). It's fixing some old data binding bugs which are kept for "backward compatibility" - unfortunately by default.
- Contrary to the documentation, the `NullValue` is the control value which is converted to `null` before setting the data source value. And `DataSourceNullValue` is the value set to the control when the data source value is null or empty. So you need to use the later, otherwice anytime you uncheck the checkbox bound to the `nullable int`, the property will be set to `null`.
- Your `Parse` method is incorrect. It's supposed to convert the control value (`bool`) to data source value (`int` or `int?`) in your case, while you are converting it to `string`. Since the default `bool` to `int` conversion and vice versa works exactly as you want, I've just removed both custom `Format` and `Parse`.

Comment: Thanks very much for that answer and also for the additional explanations. I've taken another look at what NullValue and DataSourceNullValue represent on a Binding and it makes sense why things weren't working. I've also set the FormattingEnabled as you've suggested.

Comment: Also, I need to keep the Parse and Format procedures in place because there are some fields in the DB that are a string and can contain either a string value or a 'flag' (i.e. settings; not my idea but meh, I have to work with it); so I've changed FSetDataBinding to FSetDataBinding<T> where T : class to allow me to reflect the BindingObject and find the type of the property and add Format / Parse only if it's being bound to a string value, since I still want "0" and "1" values for the string, instead of their literal "false" and "true" values going into the DB.

Comment: Ok, but at least when handling `Parse` event, check the [`ConvertEventArgs.DesiredType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.converteventargs.desiredtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property - if it is a `typeof(string)`, then do `bool` to `string` conversion, if it's not - either handle it correctly or leave it as it is, so the default conversion would take place.

Comment: I don't think that will be necessary (i.e. I can just leave it as it is), since I've changed FSetDataBinding to only add the Format and Parse events if the bound property is a typeof(string); so, if it's not, Parse and Format never get called anyway since, as you've said, the default bool to int conversions can just be used.